# Is BoundValue a valid property for a MultiPage or TabStrip control?

Tags: forms, vba, runtime-error, controls, multipage

The VBA [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264403.aspx) suggests that `BoundValue` is a valid `Control` property for a `MultiPage` control, but doesn't mention whether it is valid for a `TabStrip` control.

When I try to use `Debug.Print Me.MultiPage1.BoundValue` or `Debug.Print Me.TabStrip1.BoundValue` (even if I explicitly set the focus to the control first), then VBA throws error `450 - Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment`. That *suggests* that I'm calling the member incorrectly, or there's some contextual requirement for it to return. But I can't seem to find any state in which the property is readable.

Is the documentation incorrect (shock, horror!!!)? Is it possible to read the `BoundValue` property of a `MultiPage` or `TabStrip`? Are there any special conditions for it being readable?

Comment: Could the property be indexed and you need to specify a tab index to read it?

Comment: @Mat'sMug yep - turns out `BoundValue` returns a collection for these controls, and an index is required.

Comment: The `BoundValue` member is a member of `IControl` that is extended to each control, but while the `BoundValue` return type is `Variant`, the returned type varies by the control being accessed, so unless Rubberduck is inspecting a *Variable* of explicit type Control, it doesn't (currently) know that `BoundControl` is an available property. If it is inspecting a variable explicitly declared as type `Control`, it only knows that `BoundObject` returns a `Variant`.

Answer (score 1):

Huh, I assigned `Me.MultiPage` and `Me.TabStrip1` to variables of type `Control` and inspected the `BoundValue` in the Locals window.

The MultiPage `BoundValue` property returns the *complete* `Pages` collection, and the TabStrip `BoundValue` property returns the *complete* `Tabs` collection. For a MultiPage control, that's at odds with the documentation, and while the control's `Value` property returns a `Long` signifying the currently selected Page, having `BoundValue` return the *complete* `Pages` collection doesn't really tell me anything useful.

I guess I now know that `BoundValue` does return something, but I don't know if what it returns is useful.